# Get element from observable any array in ts

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, observable

I am having trouble accessing an element from an observable interface array that I am using. I am using an interface that contains an element time as a string. What I am looking to do is get access to the last check-in time and pull it in and compare it to my check out time so I can see how long it was between checking in and checking out. Thus I need to get the last item in the observable interface array and get the time element of that item.

So I know I have the information cause my html ngFor displays it perfectly fine but I have no idea how to access the data from within my ts to use it for calculations. I have tried getting the count/length of the observable array and then pull in the last element with that but those kept throwing errors cause from what I read you can't get the count or length of an observable array. So I tried using a foreach loop and getting the data I wanted by using a count and incrementing that until the last one and then just taking the element then but it just gives me an observable with no data and I've tried using takeLast as well but get the same issue as when I tried using count.

I really don't know what to attempt at this point or how to go about getting the data I want.

This is how I am pulling in the list from firebase.

```
  public checkInListRef:  AngularFireList<Profile>; 
  checkInList: Observable<CheckIn[]>;

  constructor(
    public geolocation: Geolocation,
    public profileProvider: ProfileProvider,
    public checkInProvider: CheckInProvider,
    public database: AngularFireDatabase,
  ) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {

        this.checkOutListRef = firebase.database().ref(`/userProfile/${user.uid}/checkOutList`);           

        this.checkInListRef = this.database.list(`/userProfile/${user.uid}/checkInList`);          

        this.checkInList = this.checkInListRef.snapshotChanges()
        .map(
          changes => {
            return changes.map(c => ({
              key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
            }))
          }
        );
      }
    });        
  }
```

And my Firebase Data Tree

[image: Firebase Data Tree]

Comment: Have you looked into ordering the list to get the last key? Add `.orderByKey().limitToLast(1)` to the query and you'll get the last key of the checkOut and checkIn list - might be easier than looping through each list.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I really have to mess around with the call to firebase and see what can be done with it.

Comment: Take a read of; https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data Once you add the `orderByKey` and `limitToLast` to your queries you'll get the last `checkIn` and last `checkOut` and you could be able to see what date is the most recent, then will be able to work out if they are checked in or out.

Comment: I am unfortunately still having a bit of trouble with this. I got the last object in my reference but I do not know how to retrieve the object data and use it to compare to a variable in my ts. I know how to get it to display in my html but I want to take the time from my last checkIn and compare it to the newest checkOut time and calculate how much time took place between those two. I got the data into an observable array with my interface as the type of array but when I try to abstract data out of it it just keeps coming up undefined.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I wasn't trying to retrieve the data in my constructor which was causing my data to come up undefined when I tried to retrieve it since I was attempting to retrieve it prior to the subscribe finishing. Thanks for the help.